# Get-HPWarrantyEntitlement Import Registry Value to store in SCCM

Tags: powershell, registry, wmi-query, sccm

Is there a way to pull this and export the information into a custom registry value so I can import into SCCM?

I've done some research and can't find any good information.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you already know how to inventory a custom registry key, so in this case I think you'd only need to write a scheduled task that runs once a day or something and writes the output to a key of your choice, or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit .mof file of the hardware inventory to get specific registry details. (make sure you research how to edit and then apply it to get the details or it will mess up the things)

It can also be done by  Administration > Client Settings > Default Client Settings > Properties > Hardware inventory > Set Classes (If its available then its simple to edit and add. I am not sure for what class you need to get the details )

FYI : The Configuration.mof file is used to define the data classes to be inventoried by hardware inventory on the client and is unchanged from Configuration Manager 2012. You can create data classes to inventory existing or custom WMI repository data classes or registry keys present on client systems.